# Using a rest plugin or a service how can one tell the token module the response is not cachable

Tags: tokens, 8

I have a rest plugin which returns an array and sends a mail. When commenting the Token::replace all works fine, the token replace function creates a BubbleableMetadata object (from what I understand of it) and than a exception is thrown:

```
LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2513810.

Also, whenever you encounter an exception, put a breakpoint on the line of code that throws that exception. You'll always find more helpful information there. In this case, that's in `\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber`.

---

Better yet, an issue with this same exact problem (when using a REST resource) on d.o, including the concrete answer with a solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/2568423

(But the above is still valid, it's the general answer.)

Comment: Thanks I have set up a context for the token replacement.

See "Setting up a render-context for the rare-case" in https://www.drupal.org/node/2513810

I also had a service that simply returned the one time login link. For that one it was sufficient enough to disable the collecting of metadata in user_pass_reset_url. So I made a copy of user_pass_reset_url and added ", TRUE" to the generating of the Url object, which fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is part which rendering happen on replace function

```
 // If a local $bubbleable_metadata object was created, apply the metadata
  // it collected to the renderer's currently active render context.
  if (!$bubbleable_metadata_is_passed_in && $this->renderer
    ->hasRenderContext()) {
    $build = [];
    $bubbleable_metadata
      ->applyTo($build);
    $this->renderer
      ->render($build);
  }
```

based on the documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/9.2.x
you can make this condition false and prevent running bypassing a bubbleable_metadata to it.

I would suggest `new BubbleableMetadata()`

```
$token->replace($meta_tag, ['node' => $entity],  ['clear' => TRUE], new BubbleableMetadata());
```